# Regex matching Numbers with ,-N and Numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to match strings in the pattern,

Numbers

, or - or N

Numbers

```
 ([0-9]+[,-N])+[0-9]+
```

Should match,

```
 87-7-6   
 86-6-2,3    
 4-N-0  
 87-7-6   
 86-14-2,3    
 4-N-0
```

Is not matching,

```
4-N-0
```

Any help?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, here. Isn't that regex invalid anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the dash in the set, otherwise it will match all characters from comma to N.

```
([0-9]+[,\-N])+[0-9]+
```

It doesn't match `4-N-0` because it doesn't fall into what you describe that it should match. If you want it to match multiple separators, add a `+` after that set:

```
([0-9]+[,\-N]+)+[0-9]+
```

Or perhaps you want to use the exact sequence `-N-` as one of the separators, so that it won't match for example `4NNNNNNNN0` or `4-,-,-,-,-,0`:

```
([0-9]+([,\-]|-N-))+[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen is a reserved symbol.  should it be:
    `([0-9]+[,\-N])+[0-9]+`